# Cannot link an integration account to a logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I cannot link my Logic App to the Integration Account as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account.

In the Logic App View under Settings i cannot find Integration Account:
[My Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ton0K.png)

I also tried to Upgrade the Integration Account's Pricing Tier, but this does not work as well. Any ideas why this does not work? May it be related to my Azure subscription?

Comment: Are your Integration Account and your Logic App in the same Location (Region)?

Comment: Yes they definitely are

Comment: but you are looking in Logic App > Settings > Workflow Settings > Integration Account, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old documentation. You are looking here:

[image]

But you need to look here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Open your logic open
- In the left menu go to setting - > Workflow settings

  [Click Workflow settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV2sG.png)
- Click Integration account and select your   Integration account

  [Click Here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwNnY.png)